# C++: how is istream is converted to bool inside a conditional expression

Tags: c++, istream

The istream **operator>>** is used to read the data and the function returns reference to istream.

For example,

```
istream& operator>> (bool& val);
```

But how does the istream is converted into a bool when it is used inside the conditional statement.

For example,

```
ifstream ifs(.....);  // open the file
istream &is = (istream&)ifs;

char c;

if(is >> c)   // how the istream is been evaluated into as bool
{
    // character read
}
```

Can anyone explain how it is being converted into a bool inside a conditional expression?

Comment: `ifstream` is derived from `istream`?

Answer (score 10):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool):

> ```
>    explicit std::basic_ios::operator bool() const;
> ```
>
> Returns true if the stream has no errors occurred and is ready of I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.

So since an if statement is a boolean context, it will invoke `std::istream`'s member function operator.

Comment: `ifstream` is derived from `istream`?

Comment: @John Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

operator >> return a reference to istream (istream&).

and so you're actually writing if (istream) which is in turn calling the operator bool..

in conditionals 0 is false anything else is true -> istream has an opeartor bool that checks if the stream is ok so it will return !fail()...hence true.