# Std::getline on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    stringstream instream("a x b c d x c d");
    string line;
    bool loop;
    loop = getline(instream, line);
    return 0;
}
```

It works on gcc, but when I compile using Visual Studio 2013 I get the build error at loop = getline(instream, line):

```
cannot convert from 'std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> > to 'bool'
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Depends. What are you trying to do? What is the purpose of `loop`?

Comment: I want to know if file is ending or not. Again this is minimal code generated from a bigger project.

Comment: GCC what? There have been hundreds of GCCs. What are your compilation commands? Y'know, the nitty gritty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit boolean conversion rules [changed from C++03 to C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23236824/560648), and compiler support for this stuff varies hugely across platforms.

If you really need this, I'd use the old force-boolean trick:

```
loop = !!getline(instream, line);
```

You don't need the trick if you plonk `getline` into an `if` conditional directly, instead of first assigning it to a variable, because [`if` is special](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16777482/560648).